# ¿ Cómo hacer para que lea una linea en un txt y escribirlo en otro txt esa misma linea

Tags: java

Cómo puedo hacer teniendo dos archivos `txt` para que en un `txt` me lea una línea y esa línea me la escriba en otro `txt` y así sucesivamente hasta fin de linea.

Lo puedo hacer manteniendo el `bufferReader` de uno y escribirlo en el otro con `println`?

```
import java.io.*;

public class escribir {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileWriter fichero = null;
        PrintWriter pw = null;
        try {
            fichero = new FileWriter("prueba.txt");
            pw = new PrintWriter(fichero);
            try {
                File archivo = null;
                FileReader fr = null;
                BufferedReader br = null;
                // Apertura del fichero y creacion de BufferedReader para poder
                // hacer una lectura comoda (disponer del metodo readLine()).
                archivo = new File("archivo.txt");
                fr = new FileReader(archivo);
                br = new BufferedReader(fr);

                // Lectura del fichero
                String linea;
                while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                pw.println(linea);
            }
                }
                try {
                    if (null != fr) {
                        fr.close();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                // Nuevamente aprovechamos el finally para 
                // asegurarnos que se cierra el fichero.
                if (null != fichero) {
                    fichero.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Este es el código que tengo, funciona bien pero me marca muchos errores no graves como que variables nunca se usan. como puedo mejorar este código

¿ Cómo puedo hacer para saber si se han cerrado los dos archivos?

Comment: Muéstrenos qué intentó.

Comment: Hecho, editado.

Answer (score 1):

> Como puedo hacer para saber si se han cerrado los dos archivos?

Para dejar de lado es preocupación , lo mejor sería emplear [try-Resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Agregaré una forma de hacer su tarea mucho "mejor" , *para este método es necesario que los dos archivos existan*

```
String line="";
 try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("prueba.txt"))) {
   try (BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("archivo.txt"));) {
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
          bw.write(line);
          bw.newLine();
       }
    }
 }
```

> Como es una tarea sencilla de copiar el mismo contenido a otro archivo
>   , sería conveniente que tome en consideración emplear el copiado de
>   archivos directamente o emplear el método de @Gustavo Garcia

**Update**

En base a su comentario , de añadir en lugar de reemplazar deberá añadir el segundo parámetro a `FileWriter` que significará si realiza el `append` o no  , si desea esto ,  solo añadir `TRUE` como segundo parametro,  el segundo `try` quedaría

```
 try (BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("archivo.txt",true)))
```

> `try-Resources` a partir de Java 7 en adelante , anteriores a Java 7 , deberá usar el `finally` :)

Comment: Gracias por el codigo, con ese codigo no tendría que cerrar los flujos de archivos?. solo puedo usar esta api java.io*. es una pena que solo nos encasillen por un camino

Comment: No . para eso se emplea `try-Resource` . para "autocerrar" , revisar el enlace en mi respuesta para más detalle.

Comment: Y como podria hacerlo para que no haga una copia en el txt que se escribe, si no que continue por donde esta el puntero, es decir que añada. y ese codigo de try-resource es java 7?

Comment: @Lugia actualicé mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

> Cómo puedo hacer teniendo dos archivos txt para que en un txt me lea una línea y esa línea me la escriba en otro txt y así sucesivamente hasta fin de linea.

Lo que intentas hacer es básicamente una copia de archivos. Para este fin puedes apoyarte en `java.nio` que es una API más moderna para manejo de archivos y flujos.

**Ejemplo**

```
Path path = Paths.get("<directorio origen>", "<archivo origen>");
Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
try {
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, charset);
    Path out = Paths.get("<directorio destino>", "<archivo destino>");
    Files.write(out, lines);
} catch(IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: java.nio puede usarse en un servelet?

Comment: Yo lo que quiero es descargarlo de una carpeta del servidor.